# What's the difference between enclosing and not enclosing HTML within PHP?

Tags: php, html, syntax

What's the difference between the following two pieces of code? Version B seems harder to read, with excessive use of open and closing tags, but I find a lot of tutorials and examples using this format. Is there a preferred approach, meaning a procedural reason for one over the other, or is this personal preference?

Version A (enclosed in php)

```
<?php 
    $test = array('a','b','c'); 

    if (isset($test))
        { 
        echo    '<div id="testmessage">
                <h2>
                    Test Message Below
                </h2>
                <ul>';

        foreach ($test as $t) 
            { 
            echo '<li>'.$t.'</li>';
            }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

        } 
?>
```

Version B (Multiple open and closing tags)

```
<?php   $test = array('a','b','c'); 
        if (isset($test)){ 
?>

    <div id="testmessage">
        <h2>
            Test Message Below
        </h2>
        <ul>

    <?php 
        foreach ($test as $t) 
        { 
    ?>

    <li><?php echo $t; ?></li>

    <?php 
        } 
    ?>

        </ul>
    </div>

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real difference, but it is just not encouraged.

And I give you version C which might read a little better than B:

```
<?php   
    $test = array('a','b','c'); 
    if (isset($test)): ?>

    <div id="testmessage">
        <h2>
            Test Message Below
        </h2>
        <ul>

    <?php foreach ($test as $t): ?>

    <li><?php echo $t; ?></li>

    <?php endforeach;    ?>

        </ul>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: As a matter of personal preference, I hate this style, because it reminds me of VB too much, and VB makes me cringe. :)

Comment: @SpikeX ahh but it is much easier to follow then random `}` and `{`

Comment: Not if you indent correctly. ;) Your HTML *should* line up with the brackets as if they were inside of them.

Comment: @SpikeX lol no real indenting with HTML and it usually gets screwed up a lot :-P

Answer (score 0):

- A looks like the standard hack-away style of combining PHP and HTML
- B looks like a template for a native PHP template engine (e.g. Zend View)

It's really just a style-thing, however I prefer B in combination with a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

While you might think that B is harder to read, it is actually easier to maintain.  What you have there can be loosely described as a template.

When you start to embed HTML like version A in PHP, what happens if you need to change the look of your page later on? or what happens when you want to change the layout of your page?

By combining technologies like CSS, javascipt/jquery with your html, managing your site headers, footers and main content blocks becomes more organized.

I think you'll find using templates will make your life easier in the long run.  Before you go off and think you need to wrap one on your own,  there are [many template engines to choose from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29).

Answer (score -1):

Nothing, except the memory that PHP uses in storing those HTML strings. By not including the HTML in the PHP scripts you're ultimately reducing the size (and strain) of the PHP parser, because the PHP script that it reads will ultimately be smaller.

Version B is better, but only slightly. In most cases, you won't notice the difference.

Answer (score -1):

There's no practical difference -- just a matter of style.

You might prefer the second way because you don't need to escape quotation marks, etc. in the HTML.

Comment: When thinking pragmatically, version A is inadvisable because it is hard to maintain.